# Scroll effect that changes the position of divs in a certain way

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, css-animations

I would like to achieve an effect where the circles ([*div*s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Div_and_span)) move in a certain way when the page scrolls down.

I would like the first five *divs* to be visible on the page by default.

By scrolling down, the first div escapes behind the screen and the second one enters the previous place of the first one, the third one enters the place of the second one and so on.
The sixth div takes the place of the fifth, i.e., the sixth appears on the screen.

I suspect that such a system requires advanced, for me ;), JavaScript logic.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 200vh;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

#skill-map {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 45px;
}

#skill-map div {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  line-height: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
}

#skill-map div:hover {
  border-radius: 40%;
}

#first {
  background-color: #f5a623;
  left: 15%;
  top: 10%;
}

#second {
  background-color: #00bcd4;
  left: 7.5%;
  top: 40%;
}

#third {
  background-color: #8bc34a;
  left: 15%;
  top: 70%;
}

#fourth {
  background-color: #f44336;
  top: 55%;
  left: 30%;
}

#fifth {
  background-color: #9c27b0;
  top: 70%;
  left: 45%;
}

#sixth {
  background-color: #4c61d7;
  top: 100%;
  left: 45%;
}

#seventh {
  background-color: #d7c24c;
  top: 130%;
  left: 45%;
}

#eight {
  background-color: #4cd7c2;
  top: 160%;
  left: 45%;
}

#ninth {
  background-color: #d74c61;
  top: 190%;
  left: 45%;
}

#tenth {
  background-color: #d26e37;
  top: 220%;
  left: 45%;
}
```

```html
<div id="skill-map">
  <div id="first">1</div>
  <div id="second">2</div>
  <div id="third">3</div>
  <div id="fourth">4</div>
  <div id="fifth">5</div>
  <div id="sixth">6</div>
  <div id="seventh">7</div>
  <div id="eight">8</div>
  <div id="ninth">9</div>
  <div id="tenth">10</div>
</div>
```

Illustration of what I would really like to do:

[image: Illustration of what I would really like to do]